# wordpress full height background image avada

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site with avada and fusion core. How can I set a full width containers height, or a background image height?

Like this: http://evowpthemes.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/brooklyn-WordPress-full-screen-theme.jpg